# Why do some process control blocks hold many of the same information as thread control blocks?

Tags: multithreading, process, kernel

If each process has at least one thread, then why doesn't just the thread control block hold the registers and program counter. It seems a waste that some kernels would implement the same information in the process control blocks as well. Is there some other reason that this is done?

Comment: Is there a particular kernel you have in mind?

Comment: Not in particular, but it seems that the general layout of a process control block seems to include registers and the program counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the term "process" in the kernel is a leftover from the days when processes were single threaded. By "process", the kernel really means something that the kernel has to schedule. There's no simple word for "things that the kernel has to schedule" and the use of the term "process" is historic.

When you see a "process control block", what you are really seeing is the structure the kernel uses to track something that it schedules. That often includes kernel threads and includes each thread in a process.